# publish_pages only approved if user fills in the content manually?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying (so far unsuccessfully) to get a facebook auto-posting app approved for publish_pages permission, however, I noticed that the policy guidelines for publish_pages require that end-users MANUALLY fill-in the content of every post published by the app and do not allow the app to generate or auto-populate content automatically into the published post.

Does it mean that automated posting apps which create generated content will not have any way to be approved and post to a page automatically even if the page owner wants this?

For example, such an auto-posting app may be able to post automatic weather updates to a local village community news page. Why would Facebook block such a feature if in the given example this could be useful for the page owner as well as for the page followers?

Is there any other way to achieve this functionality using a different permission set perhaps?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: They do not have to manually type it there and then, it could for example also be content from their CMS. The guideline say you are not allowed to pre-fill the message with “content the app user or business didn't create.”

Comment: _“post automatic weather updates to a local village community news page. Why would Facebook block such a feature”_ - probably because they don’t want to become a pure, automated mirroring system for external content. (Plus whether _you_ had the right to even use that weather data this way, might also be questionable. If you are talking about just grabbing that from some other online service, then perhaps rather not.)

Comment: And whether weather updates would make much sense as _posts_ to begin with, is also something I’d call rather doubtful. If you have some sort of service where you get that data from in regular intervals, then a page tab app to embed a display of the latest updates might perhaps make more sense.

Comment: @misorude If the app pre-fills the content it means that the user did not create it doesn't it? the app created it... plain english

Comment: No, why would it? The app could have presented you with a text field to input the content in a previous step, it could be part of a CMS that allows to publish articles the users did _create_ to social media, etc.